# find string inside a line in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to find the answer with **data-correct="1"**. Here is my source text:

```
<ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-ques"><b>1.</b> What the capital of Bangladesh?
 </li>
                                <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="a" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                a. Chittagong                       
                        </li>
                                <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="b" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                b.Khulna                            
                        </li>
                                <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="c" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                c.Satkhira                      
                        </li>
                                <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-correct="1" # name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                d.Dhaka
                        </li>                                   
                </ul>
```

my code:

```
ans_block = soup.find_all('ul', attrs = {'class': 'list-group'})
my_answer = q.find('li', attrs = {'class':'answer'}).find(re.compile('data-correct="1"')).string
```

Its returns **None** instead of **d.Dhaka** as result.

Your answer will be appreciated.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a regular expression. It's more convenient to search for all `li` tags with css class `answer` and the `data-correct` attribute with value `'1'`:

```py
my_answer = q.find('li', attrs = {'class':'answer', 'data-correct' : '1'}).text.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your data as html and you can find `li` tag and give additional `attrs` in `find` method to get text

```
html="""<ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-ques"><b>1.</b> What the capital of Bangladesh?
     </li>
                                    <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="a" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                    a. Chittagong                       
                            </li>
                                    <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="b" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                    b.Khulna                            
                            </li>
                                    <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-ans="c" data-correct="0" name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                    c.Satkhira                      
                            </li>
                                    <li class="answer" data-qid="1" data-correct="1" # name="ans_4665" class="rd_ques_ans">
                                    d.Dhaka
                            </li>                                   
                    </ul>"""


soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
main=soup.find("ul",class_="list-group")
main.find("li",attrs={"class":"rd_ques_ans","data-correct":"1"}).get_text(strip=True)
```

Ouput:

```
'd.Dhaka'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to run your code and getting the following error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'**. can you please suggest me how to fix this? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Oh there is 2 class inside li tags in which it is taking `"class"`:`"rd_ques_ans"` so you can chang e occorading to that

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. It's working. 

I'm facing another problem with the following pattern
 `<p class="answer"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i> holy place</p>` 
I'm trying this way: 
`ans.find('p', attrs={'class':'answer','i':'fa fa-circle'}).get_text(strip=True)` but getting None.
can you please suggest me how to get the text 'holy place'? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mehady you should create another post  with code so  it will be better for understanding

Comment: thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion I've created another post, [here is the link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082078/find-string-with-tag-search-inside-a-line-using-beautifuloup)
Can you please take a look? 
Thanks again in advance.