# Find string with tag search inside a line using Beautifuloup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract **holy place** from `<p class="answer"> <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> holy place</p>`

and **plays** from
`<p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> plays</p>`

**HTML Source Code**

```
 <div class="card card-custom custom-color">
                <h1 class="card-header card-custom-font">A pilgrim is a person who undertakes a journey to a --- <br>
                </h1>

                                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> holy place</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> a mosque</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> a bazar</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> a new country</p>
                        </div>
                                            </div>

<div class="card card-custom custom-color">
                <h1 class="card-header card-custom-font">Shakespeare is known mostly for his--- <br>
                </h1>

                                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> poetry</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> novels</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> autobiography</p>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p class="answer"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> plays</p>
                        </div>
                                            </div>
```

**My code**

```
question_block = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'card card-custom custom-color'})

right_answer = question_block.find('p', attrs={'class':'answer','i':'fa fa-circle'}).get_text(strip=True)
```

Getting output: `None`

Thanks in advance and your answer will be highly appreciated.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the appropriate css pattern on each question block. In this case `.answer > .fa-circle` will move you adjacent to the value you want, and `next_sibling` will then return the value you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''your html'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
question_blocks = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'card card-custom custom-color'})

for q in question_blocks:
    # print(q)
    print(q.select_one('.card-header').text)
    print(q.select_one('.answer > .fa-circle').next_sibling.strip())
    print('*' * 50)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @QHarr. This is what I was looking. working perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken you data as html where i have used css selector to locate element `i` tag and looping over it to find previous tag which contains correct answer text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
main_div=soup.select("p > i.fa.fa-circle")
for data in main_div:
    print(data.find_previous('p').text)
```

Output:

```
holy place
plays
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select the `p` with class name `answer` and extract the text inside it.

```
x = soup.find('p', class_="answer")
print(x.text)
```

This code will extract only **holy place** and **plays** from `p` tags.

```
p = soup.findAll('p', class_='answer')
for i in p:
    if i.text.strip() in ('plays', 'holy place'):
        print(i.text.strip())
```

```
Output:

holy place
plays
```

Comment: Thanks @Ram for your reply. But I need only **holy place** among 4 and the sequence is not the same for all list. Can you please suggest how I can do that?

Comment: @Mehady You can do a simple string matching. Only select those ```p``` tags whose text is "holy place".

Comment: Thanks again for your reply @Ram, I have edited the source code. Can you please have a look and suggest me?

Comment: thanks again. I've added two block in source code, I might have 1M block of data. So I can not string search for all answers. I hope you have got my point. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Mehady You did not mention all these things in your question ? Post clearly what would you expect from us in the question. Thanks!

Comment: sorry that I could not make you understand my question. But thanks for your help. You can have a look QHarr answer. thanks again friend.